# Shrink button and move them to navigation bar when user scroll down

Tags: swift

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Fullscreen:
[image]
I don't know what is it name so I could not search it. I tried to search the title but nothing like what I want.

If you can pass me a link or a tutorial, I will really appreciate.

Comment: That doesn’t look like a navigation bar. Navigation bar is at top of screen. This thing looks like a custom view at bottom of screen.

Comment: It is actually at the top of the screen

Comment: Well it still doesn’t look like a nav bar.

Comment: @matt I updated the fullscreen of the app. If it isn't a nav bar, so I need to make a custom view or there is any other solutions to achieve this?

Comment: It looks entirely custom to me. Which is good, as it will make the frozen animation in conjunction with scrolling much easier to accomplish.

Comment: I see, thank you alot. I will try to research customView animation now.